# Is there a way to obtain the version of liblapack.a?

Tags: lapack

I installed lapack 3.4.2 and 3.5.0 by compiling them with cmake. In my installation dir of lapack 3.5.0 I find a file `./pkgconfig/lapack.pc` saying `Version: 3.4.2`. So I'm not sure I really installed lapack 3.5.0 there.

Is there a way to obtain the version of lapack directly form the lib liblapack.a (or LAPACK.lib under Windows) ? For example from a routine in the library or with a specific tool ?

Comment: Note : after testing the solution of francis, in lapack 3.5.0 (confirmed with ilaver function) the version in `./pkgconfig/lapack.pc` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lapack function [`ilaver()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d5/d1b/_i_n_s_t_a_l_l_2ilaver_8f.html) is made for you !

Its prototype is self-explaining :

```
subroutine ilaver   (   integer     VERS_MAJOR,
    integer     VERS_MINOR,
    integer     VERS_PATCH 
)
```

Here are two programs demonstrating how to use it :

- in a fortran program, complied by `gcc main.f90 -o main -llapack`

  ```
  PROGRAM VER
  IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER major, minor, patch
    CALL ilaver( major,minor, patch )
    WRITE(*,*) "LAPACK ",major,".",minor,".",patch
  END PROGRAM VER
  ```
- In a c program, compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -llapack`

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  extern ilaver_(int* major,int* minor,int* patch);

  int main()
  {

      int major=0;
      int minor=0;
      int patch=0;

      ilaver_(&major,&minor,&patch);

      printf("lapack %d.%d.%d\n",major,minor,patch);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was exactly what I was looking for. Actually, I call it through CMake. It's quite simple with the command `try_compile`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to compile anything, you can do this in Python:

```
ATL-MBP-MAC4:~ dmcdonald$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 29 2015, 06:34:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> from ctypes.util import *
>>> lapack = CDLL(find_library("lapack"))
>>> major, minor, patch = c_int(), c_int(), c_int()
>>> lapack.ilaver(byref(major), byref(minor), byref(patch))
0
>>> print("{0}.{1}.{2}".format(major.value, minor.value, patch.value))
3.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. But in my context I don't want to require Python.